# Wait element to finish load [selenium]

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) and comunicate with some bots in character.ai, the thing is, when I send the input and get the answer, I only get a small portion of the whole answer because the div is continuously changing.

Here's the piece of code I've implemented so far:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

chrome_options = Options()
ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException)

driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://beta.character.ai/chat?char=YntB_ZeqRq2l_aVf2gWDCZl4oBttQzDvhj9cXafWcF8")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "#AcceptButton"))).click()

while True:
    char_msgs= WebDriverWait(driver, 10000, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "markdown-wrapper-last-msg")))

    for msg in char_msgs:
        print(msg.text)

    msg = str(input("Send message: "))
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "user-input").send_keys(msg)

    # press send button
    buttons = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn")))
    buttons[-2].click()
```

As you can see, I'm using explicit waits with [webdriverwait](/questions/tagged/webdriverwait), and although it works (because it waits until there's something), I can't seem to find a way to make the code waits until that div finish changing and get the whole answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code and used it like this
what i have done to make ii works is added condition to wait for visibility of stop button which means answer is being generated and then invisibility of stop button which indicates that it has stopped generating the answer and modified the locator to get text as `//div[contains(@class,'markdown-wrapper-last-msg')]`

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Stop Message Generation']")))
```

Full Code

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

chrome_options = Options()
ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)

driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://beta.character.ai/chat?char=YntB_ZeqRq2l_aVf2gWDCZl4oBttQzDvhj9cXafWcF8")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "#AcceptButton"))).click()

while True:
    msg = str(input("Send message: "))
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "user-input").send_keys(msg)

    # press send button
    buttons = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn")))
    buttons[-2].click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Stop Message Generation']")))
    print("here 1")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
        EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Stop Message Generation']")))
    print("here 2")
    char_msgs = WebDriverWait(driver, 10000, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'markdown-wrapper-last-msg')]")))
    print(char_msgs.text)
```

Working -> Added input as below 10 random words
[image]

Now after all words were generated
[image]

the Complete generated text was printed
[image]

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks, I was too focused on that div to even notice the other elements.